# how to set a cache size in android web view to load the page offline

Tags: android, android-studio, caching, webview, android-webview

how prevent android device from deleting my web view caches automatically
in order use my application in offline mode please help

Comment: See this post please: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: please can you read it again I've just made some changes thanks for the help